# On the parity of the coefficients of $(x+y)^n$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> The coefficients of $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$ are $1$, $3$, $3$ and $1$. They are all odd numbers. Which of the following options has coefficients that are also all odd numbers?
>
> $(\text A) \ \ (x+y)^5$
> $(\text B)  \ \ (x+y)^7$
> $(\text C)  \ \ (x+y)^9$
> $(\text D)  \ \ (x+y)^{11}$
> $(\text E) \ \ (x+y)^{13}$

---

My solution is using Pascal's triangle [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)] to calculate all the coefficients of $(\text A)$ to $(\text E)$. Finally, I find that only $(\text B)$ is the correct answer. I want to know if there is a faster way to solve this question.

**Reference**

[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)] Wikipedia contributors, "Pascal's triangle," *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia*, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pascal%27s_triangle&oldid=877891681 (accessed January 29, 2019).

**Note**

My question is different from "How does Combination formula relates in getting the coefficients of a Binomial Expansion?" The key point here is the parity.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No, my question is different. The key point is the parity.

Comment: My apologies. I assumed that it was about faster techniques of finding the coefficients of the expansion. May I suggest accepting the answer below if it has answered your question?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan That is alright. Yes, I will accept the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n \choose k$ is odd, for every $k=0,1,..,n$  if and only if $n=2^m-1$ (i.e. $n$ has only 1's in its base 2 expansion).

This is proved using [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)